# Algebraic expression for a word problem

Tags: word-problem

I'm having trouble in coming up with an algebraic expression for the below.

Assuming **"r = rooster"** and **"t = turkey"**
**r = ?**
Would it be 1/5th of turkey **"r = 1/5 * t"  ?**

> A rooster weighs 5 times less than a turkey

For the second one it is **"t = r + 8"**

> turkey weighs 8 kg more than the rooster

***Question:-
A rooster weighs 5 times less than a turkey, and the turkey weighs 8 kg more than the rooster. How much does each bird weigh?***

Comment: Yes.  Those are the equations you want to solve.

Comment: Also, the phrase "x times less than" is mathematically weak and should be avoided. It is unfortunate when it appears in math problems.

Comment: I would argue that $r = $ **the weight of a rooster** (in kg) as opposed to $r$ being an actual rooster.  Even if an apple and an orange weigh the same an apple is not in fact an orange.  This is, of course, semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, if you set it up the equations in any way and try to solve it you will know if it's right or not.

$t=5r$ (1*) and $t=r+8 $ (2*)

System of equations, put 1* into 2*.

$5r=r+8 <=> r=2,$ then put r back into 1* or 2* and you get $t=10$